# Adding categories in rwd theme

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1

Apologize if this is a duplicate question, I've tried almost every solution there is. I'm tasked with adding a menu in the RWD theme (1.9) that lists the products categories, that will also allow me to go to each category landing page.

I' am seriously stuck. This is the last thing I've tried.

So this is in template/catalog/category/category.phtml
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/218a1198e8d9364ee611

And this is in layout/catalog.xml
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dee56616ad7862240595

The above didn't add anything, nothing appeared.

This is a fresh localhost install and my first time using Magento. I am really confused here.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I search on google "add categories in magento", it showed numerous results. All of those answers will help you to create categories in magento.

In general, you don't need to do anything in code wise. If you are new in magento, first you need to study, how can you use admin side of magento, what are the features that is providing by admin side. If you have done a basic familiarization with admin side of magento, you would not ask this question here :)

Any ways, you can create a category through `Catalog  >  Manage Categories`. There you have provision to add new category, edit an existing category etc. [Follow this link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-categories) for more details.

If you have a root catalog/categories exist for your current store, then menu will appear automatically in the frontend. In order to set up those things, you need to first create a store, then set it as your default store, then assign a root category for that store. These all steps you can do through admin side. You can do this operation via `System  >  Manage Stores`. For more info, you can use this **[link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/catalog/creating_and_assigning_root_categories)**

If you need to do this through programmatically, you can [refer this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10016/how-to-set-root-category-for-all-stores-in-a-website).

[Another link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-and-managing-categories) to get a better idea

Comment: Ah sorry, I haven't done much research. This task is for a possible job and I've been trying to just figure this part out. It's quite complicated.

Comment: I've added a category, but no menu appears on the frontend.

Comment: go with this info.. once you familiarized with admin side, you are good to shoot it out.

Comment: see second part of my answer.

Comment: Isn't using the default store okay, or do I need to create a store from the menu?

Comment: Your system now uses default store right? Then you need to set root catalog for that store. you can do it through `system > manage stores`. Select the default store. There you can select the category and then save. that will show category in frontend

Comment: Okay, so I set the root page to technology and the one product is tagged with, nice. So how can I get that in the navigation? for example, the fake product is called firetv, so how can I get the breadcrumbs to do /technology/firetv?